# Change data.frame format to label all columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have run into this problem before and had a lengthy work around, now I thought to post here.  Thanks in advance!

I am trying to `merge()` the following small data.frame (named HelpData) with a much larger data.frame (not included).  The code below reads in HelpData, and looks at the `head()` and the `str()`.

```
HelpData <- structure(list(`(Intercept)` = c(-0.416714383410771, -0.484420889203111, 
0.8852233181836, -0.00573901277840992, 0.819352447999715, -0.0219740206432874, 
-0.725659038472068, 0.842129479134587, 0.231330671497113, 1.67161285063258, 
0.562139877718068, -0.56702368527195, -1.09763116254353, -0.32410756195596, 
0.166964590752782, -0.812461815971089, -0.609301958979508, 0.368263149194526, 
0.964304770606394, -0.887610418600415, -0.555998527038864, -0.0940912475713328, 
0.706094048452952, -0.500888453405431)), .Names = "(Intercept)", row.names = c("CAL_F01", 
"CAL_F17", "CAL_F19", "CAL_F23", "CAL_F43", "CAL_M33", "CAL_M36", 
"COL_P01", "COL_P03", "COL_P05", "COL_P06", "COL_P07", "COL_P08", 
"COL_P09", "COL_P10", "COL_P12", "COL_P13", "PAT_F02", "PAT_F03", 
"PAT_F04", "PAT_F05", "PAT_M02", "PAT_M03", "PAT_M04"), class = "data.frame")

head(HelpData)
str(HelpData)
```

As seen in the `str()` of HelpData, the object is a data frame with 24 obs. of  1 variable.  The “Intercept” column is the only one that is recognized.  However I want to `merge()` based on the AnimalID field which is not labeled.  The code below results in the error

Code:

```
 colnames(HelpData)<- c("CougarID", "RandInt")
```

Error:

```
 “'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]”  This the first coumne is not regonized and thus cannot be named.
```

What is the best what to change the data format so I can have the same two columns, but the ability to name the first?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cougar ID's are store in row names *not* actually in a column of data. To change that,

```
HelpData$CougarID = rownames(HelpData)
```

should do the trick.

Then you can also ammend:

```
names(HelpData)[1] = "RandInt"
```